# Making a div absolute to specific div

Tags: html, css, css-position

Is it possible to make a `div` absolute to a specific relative `div` rather than just the parent?

For example. I have a div that's contained inside of a row. But, I want it to be absolute in the `section` rather than the `row`. Both divs are positioned `relative` because of a WordPress themes styling. If I use position `absolute` it will just make it absolute to the `row`.

How can I get around this issue?

```css
.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.row {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: #000000;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No...that's not how positioning works....but *why* are the divs positioned relatively....it's not necessary unless you have a specific reason for it. Just override the positioning on the `.row`.

Comment: If possible place your div outside row so it will relative to section.

Comment: It's not possible. I'm using the Divi theme on WordPress and I'm only able to place modules outside of the row. I also can't remove the positioning from the `row` as it needs to be relative.

Comment: if any child has absolute position, then it rely on its own parent not the immediate parent.

Comment: Is the only way I could do this is by setting all of the `divs` positions to unset until I get to the div I want to be the parent?

Comment: Yes...but you haven't said **why** the row needs to be `position:relative`...I suspect it does not.

Comment: @jordan You can use `position: fixed`...fixed positioned elements are always relative to the document, not a parent element.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how positioning works. A div or any other element is relevant to its parent regarding its positioning. In case you want to position an element inside the section that you have, it's better to construct your code as follows:

```
<div class="section">
  <div class="absoluteDiv">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
  </div>
</div>
```

You could find some more examples [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

Hope it helps,
Konstantinos.

Comment: I understand that this is not the best practice. However, I'm using Divi Builder and I don't have access to the code structure because it is being built on WordPress. Thank you for the advice though.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can not make a div absolute to a specific div, one way to get the results you are looking for is to add `overflow:visible;` to the row and `left:100%;` to content container. I changed the section height to `300px` for demonstration purposes but it will behave the same with `100%`.

```css
.section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  background: #f5f5f5;
}

.row {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background: #000000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow:visible;
}

.content {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```